# How to validate that a dependent row belongs to a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called Category;

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

And, I have a model called Group:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :categories

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

As you can see, a group can have many categories. When a user adds a category or updates it's group_id value, I want to check that the group belongs to that user. I don't want users adding to and update categories to another user's group. What is best practise to validate this prior to saving? Thanks

Comment: Add a check in the create and update methods in your categories_controller to check if the group id belongs to the user.

Comment: Can you also show how you create these categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
validate :ownership_of_group

def ownership_of_group
  ids = []
  ids << self.group_id
  ids << self.group_id_was if self.group_id_was.present?
  if(Group.find(ids).reject {|group| group.user_id == self.user_id}.present?)
    # if all of them is owned by the user the array will return an empty array
    errors.add(:user_id, 'You cant edit a category that is not yours')
  end
end
```

If we say group_id we get the current value that is being set by the use.
If we say group_id_was it get the old value before the update.
In the update we need to handle both in the create we have no previous value.

Comment: this is only on update if you need it on creation too just tell me

Comment: I see. So I can write my own function for validates? Nice. Yes I would like it to apply for creation too. Would that require a another validates statement? (... on: :create?) Also, the *_was usage is new to me, I don't really understand what's happening there. If the user changes the group_id, would it not validate self.group_id? (as it currently is, not what it was) Thanks

Comment: It gives me an ArgumentError at the line `validates :ownership_of_group`. It says, "You need to supply at least one validation". Should I be using `before_validation` instead of `validates`?

Comment: what is your rails version? [ref](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods)

Comment: use validate instead of validates. just that will solve your problem

Comment: did you try it? waiting for your feed back